# Can I separate networking from mapping with RestKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am building an iOS app that consumes a REST API and I was planning to use Restkit.
Following the principle of separation of concerns, I'd like to keep networking separate from parsing and mapping, so in my architecture I have designed separate classes for the three.

However, it seems with Restkit everything is bundled together:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/v2/venues/search"
                  parameters:queryParams
                     success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                 _venues = mappingResult.array;
                                 [self.tableView reloadData];
                             }
                     failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                 NSLog(@"What do you mean by 'there is no coffee?': %@", error);
                             }];
```

(From the tutorial on raywenderlich.com)

Do you know of a way to efficiently separate networking from mapping when using Restkit?

Thanks

Comment: There are a number of techniques that you can use for invoking a method on another class - delegation pattern, blocks, NSNotificationCentre - this last one probably works best with a singleton handling your data model and invoking the network code when required.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RKObjectManager` instance(s) handle the configuration for the mapping and execute (manage) the networking and mapping operation. The same is true of any other usage of RestKit really. But, that doesn't mean that your usage of `RKObjectManager` needs to be done all in one place. You can have one class which accepts the `RKObjectManager` as a parameter and sets the mapping info, probably be requesting the mapping for each object from your model classes so that this object only knows about the path info. Then you can have another class which knows which paths to interrogate for a particular app problem domain data requirement and triggers the network communication.

It's really up to you to decide how you want to split the logic across your architecture.

Comment: Can you make an example of how to go about that in practice ? As you see in my example mapping and networking are done together. How would you separate them?

Comment: The example code in the question is just asking for content at a path. It known nothing about networking or mapping. That request could go to a local file, it could return from a local database.